# An alternative characterization of nilpotent groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Having problem with the following proposition:

A group $G$ is nilpotent if and only if $\gamma_{m}(G)=<e>$ for some $m$ where $\gamma_{1}(G)=G$, $\gamma_{2}(G)=[G,G]$ and $\gamma_{i}(G)=[\gamma_{i-1}(G),G]$. (This is an exercise in Hungerford's Algebra, Chapter 2, section 7, exercise 4.)

I have proved that the each $\gamma_{i}(G)$ is normal in $G$ and $\gamma_{i+1}(G)\subset\gamma_{i}(G)$. Moreover, I observe that $\gamma_{2}(G)=G^{(1)}$( the first derived subgroup of G) which implies the connection between $\gamma_{i}(G)$ and solvable group. However, I fell there is something which is crucial for this problem are left out. Could somebody give me a tip in the right direction? 
Thanks!

Comment: What is your definition of a nilpotent group? A group having a finite central series?

Comment: Yes, $C_{n}(G)=G$ for some $n$ where $C_{n-1}(G)\subset C_{n}(G)$ is a finite central series.

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem by applying some facts as follows :

$C_{1}=C(G),C_{i+1}(G)/C_{i}(G)=C(G/C_{i}(G))$ then $[C_{i+1},G]<C_{i}(G)$. And it is easy to verify that $C_{i+1}(G)=\{g\in G:[g,G]<C_{i}(G)\}$.

if G is nilpotent, by induction, $\gamma_{i}(G)<C_{n-i+1}(G)$. Then $\gamma_{n+1}(G)=[\gamma_{n}(G),G]<[C_{1}(G),G]=<e>$.

Conversely, if $\gamma_{n}(G)=<e>$ then by induction $\gamma_{i}(G)<C_{n-i}(G)$. Therefore $G=\gamma_{1}(G)<C_{n-1}(G)$ and G is nilpotent.

Answer (score 0):

Hungerford defines nilpotent groups as those having a finite upper central series (the centers' series):

$$1=:Z_0\le Z_1\le Z_2\le\ldots\le Z_n=G\;,\;\;Z_i/Z_{i-1}:=Z(G/Z_{i-1})\;,\;\;1\le i\le n$$

Well, now just prove inductively that the series you're given is central, meaning

$$[\gamma_i,G]\le\gamma_{i+1}$$

and the relations

$$Z_k\le\gamma_{n-k-1}\le Z_{k+1}$$

which makes it clear that the upper central series ends at $\;G\;$ iff the lower central series end at $\;1\;$ .

Comment: Thank you for your help! I can use the the fact that $H/K<Z(G/K)$ if and only if $(H,G)<K$ where K is normal in G and $K<H$ to prove the right side of the above relations. But the left is still not clear.

Comment: By induction, if the inequality $Z_{n-k}<\gamma_{k}<Z_{n-k+1}$ holds , then how can one prove that $\gamma_{k+1}=(\gamma_{k},G)>Z_{n-k-1}$?